# dplyr ifelse mutate reference to variable outside the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple problem but i haven't figured out the solution yet. I don't know how to reference to a variable outside the data frame when I'm using dplyr. Here is a small chunk of code:

```
library(dplyr)

var <- 1

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", "c"), col2 = c(1, 2, 3))

df %>% mutate(col2 = ifelse(var == 1, col2 + var, col2))
```

Result:

```
  col1 col2
1    a    2
2    b    2
3    c    2
```

Desired output:

```
  col1 col2
1    a    2
2    b    3
3    c    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rowwise` and `sum`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(col2 = ifelse(var == 1, sum(col2,var), col2))
```

```
  col1   col2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         2
2 b         3
3 c         4
```

Comment: Sounds great! is it still vectorised?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge: yes!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a `dplyr` specific issue but when you have a condition to check of length 1 use `if` and `else` instead of vectorized `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(col2 = if(var == 1) col2 + var else col2)

#  col1 col2
#1    a    2
#2    b    3
#3    c    4
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R` for this

```
i1 <- df$col2 == var
df$col2[i1] <- df$col2[i1] + var
```

-output

```
> df
  col1 col2
1    a    2
2    b    2
3    c    3
```

---

Or use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[col2 == var, col2 := col2 + var]
```